# No way to get sound from rear audio ports when headphones (front) are connected

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

Whenever I have headphones connected in the front jack I'm unable to get sound from my rear ports (this means that the only way to switch audio device is to physically remove the headphones before audio starts player over the rear jack again). Normally the only thing I see in the sound manager is an `Analog Output - Build-in Audio`. When headphones are connected, they show up perfectly in the sound manager, but both the `Headphones` and the `Analog Output` will output all audio through the headphones rather than one entry for the headphones (front) and one entry for the speakers (back).

The audio device itself is `00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)` (from lspci).

I tried installing the `Realtek ALC898 Audio Codec` linux driver but to no avail. Running Ubuntu GNOME 14.10 but even with older versions and other Debian based distro's this problem has existed.